# Is there a better way to reference a route by name in a link with AngularDart?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have many named routes in my AngularDart app. I create links the old fashioned way, like this:

```html
<a href="#/activities">Go</a>
```

That seems brittle. If I change the path or change the strategy away from hash change, I need to change all my links.

Can I do something like:

```html
<a ng-link="activities">Go</a>
```

Where `activities` is the name of the route from my routes config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For now you can use router to generate those URLs for you.

```
router.url('activities', {});
```

The second parameter (should probably be optional) is a map of parameter values. For example, if you have a path like `/activity/:activityId` then you can do:

```
router.url('activity', {'activityId', '12345'});
```

URL generator also honors current state of routes, so lets say you had an active route like  `foo.bar.baz`, and `foo` was parameterized and you somehow got a hold of bar route (ex. via `RouteProvider` or queried `router.root.getRoute('foo.bar')`) then you don't need to know the values of the `foo` route parameters to generate the URL for `baz`, you can do:

```
Route bar = router.root.getRoute('foo.bar');
router.url('baz', {}, startingFrom: bar);
```

For now you will need to manually insert the generated URL into the template:

`<a href="{{ctrl.generatedUrl}}">link</a>`

Comment: Thanks! How would you recommend connecting this to the `<a>` element?

Comment: For now manually... `<a href="{{ctrl.generatedUrl}}">link</a>`. Having a directive for it would be nice. Please file a FR.

Comment: Thanks. Your comment is the answer I was looking for :)